# O que é o ideal: Especificar a pergunta ou torná-la mais útil à comunidade?

Tags: debate

Esses dias estava tentando interpretar um código de solução do "[problema do barbeiro dorminhoco](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/%7Ebosco.sobral/ensino/ine5645/Lab3.pdf)", porém fiquei com uma dúvida na implementação de um semáforo chamado "seatbelt" no código-exemplo que estava lendo. Pensei então em perguntar aqui em busca de uma luz, mas então me surgiu uma outra dúvida:
**Como deveria perguntar isso?**

### Qual a utilidade do semáforo "seatbelt" na implementação do problema do barbeiro dorminhoco?

Ao especificar a pergunta, diminuiria o escopo dela, mostraria que não estava em busca apenas da resposta e conseguiria a resposta que eu estava procurando.

### Como funciona a implementação do problema do barbeiro dorminhoco?

Se eu fizesse uma pergunta mais ampla como essa (e ela fosse respondida), seria respondido mais do que era necessário para **mim**, mas seria uma pergunta (e uma resposta) mais útil para a comunidade no geral, já que teria uma interpretação completa do código como resposta, mas fiquei com receio também de pessoas acharem que estava pedindo a resposta de algo sem mostrar minha tentativa de interpretação/etc.

No stack overflow, qual seria o melhor **formato** de pergunta? E por quê?

Answer (score 8):

De forma geral é melhor o que é mais útil para a comunidade, sempre. Claro que precisa atender o que deseja.

E claro que a pergunta precisa ser bem feita, porque se a pergunta for genérica, mas não fundo não tem problema específico ou é algo puramente conceitual, se for algo que dá chance para muitas respostas diferentes e ninguém sabe ao certo o que seria certo, aí fica complicado. Digo isso porque se não tiver um contexto maior as duas perguntas poderiam ser ruins.

Porém no exemplo a primeira mais específica tem uma chance de ser interpretada como uma pergunta conceitual. A segunda provavelmente seria interpretado como um "faz pra mim". Reforço que depende do contexto.

Não vejo como a especificidade do assunto possa ser pior para a comunidade. Ser amplo geralmente é ruim. Então a ideia aqui parece ser uma premissa errada. Se específico no assunto é diferente de ser específico para o indivíduo. E ser específico no assinto não se contrapõe a ser mais útil à comunidade.

Bem feitas ambas serão úteis à comunidade. A primeira só tem um pouco mais de chance de ser compreendida corretamente, se tiver junto outros elementos.

A filosofia do site sempre foi atender as pessoas em geral com dúvidas de um indivíduo. Poucas pessoas entendem (novatos e muitos veteranos) que o objetivo do site não é resolver o problema de uma pessoa sem que isso não ajude outras pessoas de alguma forma.

Comment: sim, esse "faz pra mim" que me deixou com o pé atrás. Não consegui pensar numa boa maneira de elaborar uma pergunta como essa e ao mesmo tempo mostrar o que "já fiz" (leia-se interpretei) sem perder o foco da pergunta, e não poderia adicionar como resposta também já que estaria incompleto. Obrigado pelo esclaecimento!